# Further developments of Cartier–Gabriel–Kostant–Milnor–Moore Structure Theorem for cocommutative Hopf algebras

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras, bialgebras

A very well-known theorem in Hopf algebra theory (see, for example, [Lorenz - A tour of representation theory](https://books.google.be/books?id=PUNwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA496&lpg=PA496&dq=%22cartier-gabriel-kostant%20theorem%22&source=bl&ots=XbCJjSY9IN&sig=ACfU3U0LidrfkLOEOMSOpEJb-EgBqvnUaw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEvpj2xu_pAhUF-qQKHWS7ACYQ6AEwAnoECBcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22cartier-gabriel-kostant%20theorem%22&f=false) or the EGNO book ([Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych, and Ostrik - Tensor categories](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf))) states that if $H$ is a cocommutative Hopf algebra over an algebraically closed field $\Bbbk$ of characteristic zero then $$H \cong U(P(H)) \mathbin\# \Bbbk G(H)$$ as Hopf algebras, where $P(H)$ is the space of primitive elements of $H$ and $G(H)$ the group of group-like elements. As far as I know, this theorem is attributed differently to many people, but I believe the list in the title should be comprehensive of all of them. For example, I know that the Milnor–Moore part of the theorem is the one stating that an irreducible cocommutative Hopf algebra $H'$ over a field of characteristic zero satisfies $H' \cong U(P(H'))$.

I know that Nichols proved, in [The Kostant structure theorem for $K/k$ Hopf algebras](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(85)90052-3), an analogue of the full CGKMM theorem for Hopf algebroids of the form $(K,H)$, where $K$ is a field extension of $\Bbbk$, that Moerdijk and Mrčun proved, in [On the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebroid](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20764270?seq=1), an analogue of Milnor–Moore for bialgebroids and that, later, Kališnik and Mrčun proved, in [A Cartier–Gabriel–Kostant structure theorem for Hopf algebroids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870812003477), an analogue of the full Cartier–Gabriel–Kostant–Milnor–Moore for Hopf algebroids over the algebra $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathcal{M})$ of smooth functions with compact support over a smooth real manifold $\mathcal{M}$.

Is anybody aware of some further developments/extensions of this result to other classes of Hopf algebras (for example, weak Hopf algebras, general Hopf algebroids, (co)quasi-Hopf algebras, etc.)?

Otherwise, is there anybody aware of counter-examples that suggest this could not be generalized further in some direction?

**Edit:** Just to add some further motivation to this quest. Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $\Bbbk$ of characteristic zero. The coordinate algebra $\mathscr{O}(G)$ is a commutative Hopf algebra. If we consider the subspace $\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ$ of $\mathsf{Hom}_\Bbbk\left(\mathscr{O}(G),\Bbbk\right)$ formed by all those linear functionals which vanish on a finite-codimensional ideal, this is a cocommutative Hopf algebra. By the CGKMM Theorem we know that
$$\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ \cong U\left(P\left(\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ\right)\right) ~\#~ \Bbbk G\left(\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ\right).$$
It happens that $P\left(\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ\right) \cong \mathfrak{g}$, the tangent Lie algebra to $G$ at the neutral element, and $G\left(\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ\right) \cong \mathsf{Alg}_\Bbbk\left(\mathscr{O}(G),\Bbbk\right) \cong G$, so that
$$\mathscr{O}(G)^\circ \cong U\left(\mathfrak{g}\right) ~\#~ \Bbbk G,$$
where on the right-hand side $G$ is considered as a discrete group and $U(\mathfrak{g}) \cong \mathsf{Dist}_G$, the hyperalgebra of distributions on $G$.

Is there anybody aware of some further results like this one for groupoids?

Comment: There is an operadic version of Milnor-Moore's theorem which characterizes enveloping algebras in arbitrary symmetric monoidal categories (whenever this notion makes sense). This is theorem 6.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306212.

Answer (score 2):

The super version of the theorem, refers to "*hopf superalgebras*", or "*$\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded hopf algebras*" or "*hopf algebras in the braided monoidal category of $\mathbb{CZ}_2$-modules*":
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a super-cocommutative hopf superalgebra over an algebraically closed field $k$ of char zero. Then we have the hopf superalgebra isomorphism:
$$
\mathcal{H}\cong k[G(\mathcal{H})]\ltimes_{\pi} U\big(P(\mathcal{H})\big) 
$$ 
where, $k[G(\mathcal{H})]$ is the group algebra of the the group $G(\mathcal{H})$ of the grouplikes of $\mathcal{H}$, $U\big(P(\mathcal{H})\big)$ is the universal enveloping algebra of the lie superalgebra $P(\mathcal{H})$ of the primitive elements of $\mathcal{H}$ and the smash product $\ltimes_{\pi}$ is with respect to the representation of $G(\mathcal{H})$ on $P(\mathcal{H})$ determined by: $\pi:G\to Aut(P)$, $\pi(g)x=gxg^{-1}$, for all $g\in G$, $x\in P$.

This has been an old result, first shown by Kostant, at:
[B.Kostant, "*Graded manifolds, graded Lie theory and prequantization*", Differential Geometrical Methods in Mathematical Physics. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 570, p. 177-306, (1977)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0087788))

**P.S.:** What i do not know, is whether there is a corresponding version of the theorem for Hopf algebras in braided monoidal categories. I am not aware of some reference in that direction (although, i think the generalization should not be that difficult to prove). The only related reference i know of is [Braided bialgebras of Hecke-type, A. Ardizzoni, C.Menini, D. Stefan, Journal of Algebra 321 (2009) 847–865](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869308X00250/1-s2.0-S0021869308005590/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHIaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDzBwCr8%2FagteEL5QyMFhk7jQfBxuJM4V4EqjlW4y7Y8wIhAP7w2tFJHcSXTF38l6omYj58L4PkF0MKxqW3D%2Bwv5fjVKr0DCNv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAxoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgxoRRm%2FSIv7gVlWVT0qkQPY%2FFFOzAOYgHlbCNQqKds8Os82JJuonw2NTxIIF7%2FiQNOp4uzl%2BIk1HtBt0YRTHayDd7CtesMkKCcuUx6FxbfAHDOK5%2BHxvNJzVWuhiq0sXXLjCVJXZ%2F3wL9GhnzVLQpd%2F%2ByfNsjPBcWVMZWn%2F59nHS8TOyqTKCoRJQOYtslFbp8rND51sg35XpA5hkwbgrQ0yIECCqpJC9zzfDU13dkort20ZTLNVtLl0K8cLs84Q4Tncb907wDMpWIkb%2FPHnfLqLAN3bfWRq22Z47nblAwQ4swnmmwDU0Nj3p9Y%2F5LYARRcWiPd7PAZhnElXxzbPS048RwT3HPKqibj4BVSkGUGTjNvt5O1jAux48d%2BgYP4YAHV1u3bZpSRcxRLcPNHyAeAZn2jwPuA8yuZxM7dyzavzOiZYIWEPFkllrouSfi3sE7gwS8z6Cg1jg5vHJm5Q7TPRdzSa6v3TMNNvRrjPaNW6%2BxGBGnCFbNeepQX21EYz1P658V0r1ZOt4F1jkPKEfsF8Ldrbn%2F2rnZK9e3%2FsYGrZ0DCjz%2FT2BTrqAWRVqJlY7uEiygeARRG6FH%2FiROCYg8MzKeaNirRMEJRHesjWD5%2BRc22SBrdtFzaq9ACNYqw6pXepMYzU7LKTkstZofVd5sobaFEncK%2FXUsnHK72qSGhpUcCoxLqZ6pdOryMstgoFZ5fU%2BguXooFZ214lLtVloD4QI8DMt8eNdgtX9Y9WCVDZ7aazNOJSDrswSSFdkOHcDfz46QMwuZdVRfJ%2BSOE6remHkKeWlRUJIflnoMiK5OLZXOdDdpbNgzK3gt5gV7G0HyZBHTU1gw5i0x4X2r1ybbDiRG3a6qbiuBefHUpXSWoFyT7zJQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200607T175322Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY3MRM767V%2F20200607%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=a8618fa12e2f938739d5dfdd95f5599f1484c626d61d8c51151424183e70fe4d&hash=d898e7a28480c7da6c2767508ddfa70f85e08a91ca297ab555fab203264000fb&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021869308005590&tid=spdf-17067208-e969-407b-8ac0-66b434065f6f&sid=2589681320ca714c2b8a167930f73dbe924dgxrqb&type=client), where a result -analogous to the Milnor-Moore part of the theorem- is proved for connected, braided bialgebras which are infinitesimally cocommutative (see theorem 5.5 and the resulting discussion).

**Edit:** another possible line of generalization of the theorem , has to do with the class of quasitriangular hopf algebras. These, generalise the cocommutative hopf algebras, so it is natural to consider the possibility of a "quasitriangular version" of the theorem. See for example: [Classification of quasitriangular Hopf algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/q/255767/85967)

Comment: You have my sincere gratitude for all your inputs. Alas I cannot +1 you more than once. I am leaving the question unanswered to see if somebody else shows up with other references

Comment: Thank you. I have just now realized that you have been a coauthor of A. Ardizzoni and D. Stefan, so maybe, you were already aware of their work mentioned in my PS above :)