# Classifying of low-dimensional Frobenius algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, topological-quantum-field-theory, frobenius-algebras

Does there exist a classification of finite-dimensional Frobenius algebras in low dimensional cases. This question is motivated by the following analogous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392478/low-dimensional-noncommutative-non-cocommutative-hopf-algebras) for Hopf algebras.

Comment: There are absolutely loads of them. I recently wrote a paper with Sambale about which small dimensional ones can be Morita equivalent to blocks of group algebras of finite groups, if that's of any help to you.

Comment: Since Frobenius algebras and Hopf algebras share a lot in common, why is that one of them (i.e. Hopg algebras) admit a classification in low dimensions but the other (Frobenius algebras) do not?

Comment: Can I suggest, by way of frustrating exercise, that you try to classify eight dimensional basic Frobenius algebras with one simple module? I think you may soon see why the definition is so much "floppier" and easier to satisfy than that of Hopf algebras.

Comment: @DaveBenson: Ok - thanks for the suggestion!